# How to manage a dev branch and a prod branch for Symfony with Git

Tags: git, symfony, branch

I work with friends on a Symfony project and we have two branches using git. The origin/master and the origin/dev.

The master is used for production and the dev for development as usual.

**I want the dev branch to have more files** than the production one.

For example, I want the prod branch to not have the web/app_dev.php file, and **I want the dev branch to have some test files that can be committed to the dev branch, but not considered when merging with the master branch.** However, I want the files that are both on the dev and the master version to be considered when merging from dev to master.

At the moment, when I modify a test file (for example TestController.php) on the dev branch, I can commit it to the dev branch but I makes me a conflict with the master branch because the file is not in the master branch (as it is a test file, it doesn't need to be in the prod) :

> git merge dev --no-ff

```
CONFLICT (modify/delete): src/AppBundle/Controller/TestController.php deleted in HEAD and modified in dev. Version dev of src/AppBundle/Controller/TestController.php left in tree. Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

I know I could untrack (via git rm) these test files, however I need them the be committed and pushed on the dev branch to work with my friends.

Is it possible to do what I want ? i.e : having more files in the dev version that are not considered when merging with master branch but still committed and pushed on the dev branch ?

Thanks

Comment: What is the problem with having the test files in both places?  It is difficult and unusual to do what you have in mind.

Comment: The production server doesn't need app_dev.php, config_dev.yml or test files, I'd rather have only useful files in my prod version...

Comment: I recommend maintaining these files in a separate test folder.  If you really don't even want them on the production server, then write a script which won't copy them over.

Comment: Don't use git as a deployment strategy.

Comment: Thank you. I thought git could be used for deployment via git pull.. I'll do a deployment .sh then, that removes the file I don't want

Comment: I’d look into Continuous integration for deployment. That way you can run checks, tests, and other delights before deploying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git is not good as a deployment strategy.

There is no way achieving what you want except using ugly hacks that you'll forget soon or later, and that will break your workflow.

Theses hacks will also be specific to your repository clone, and won't be pulled by other.

Use a real deployment tool that will not synchronise file you don't want to see on your production environment.

Comment: That's exactly the kind of answer I expected. Thank you ! I'll have to use a deployment tool then :)

Comment: @Azeotropy If the answer helped you, feel free to upvote it and mark it as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove CONFLICTS(manually) before pushing the code
Default it always master branch. If you want to create new branch try this command

```
git checkout_b "new_branch_name"
```

Before pushing code you always (pull the latest code its an optional), you have to merge your local branch to master branch using `git merge master`  after `git add .`
and finally do these commands

```
git commit -am "comment"
git push origin "your branch name"
```